# Unable to Shutdown after updating to 14.10 from 14.04

Tags: shutdown, 14.10, restart

After updating to Ubuntu 14.10 I have noticed that my Dell inspiron 7537 is unable to shutdown.

When I try to shutdown with UI - It keeps restarting.

When I try in terminal (i.e `sudo shutdown now`, `sudo shutdown -h 0`, `sudo shutdown -P 0`, etc) - It end-up with a black screen.

Comment: also try sudo poweroff in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try updating drivers and Grub, or disable visual settings

To disable visual effects by:

1. right click on the desktop and select "change desktop background".
2. Click the "Visual Effects" tab.
3. Change it to none.

and also try some terminal commands like

```
sudo poweroff
sudo halt
```